# Receiving a copy on Outlook 2010 (POP) of the mail sent using an Android Phone (Gmail account)

Tags: gmail, microsoft-outlook-2010

Apologizes for my clumsyness but I cannot solve this.

To send mails I use my android phone with a gmail account.
To read mails I use Outlook 2010, where the same account is set as POP.

I just use it this way because for reading is more confortable on the pc.

The problem is that all the mails I send through my smartphone, will be downloaded later on the outlook.

How could I avoid to get a copy of all the messages I sent? and of course I am not adding myself as CC. Please help, I am sorry I cant find out myself.

Comment: Do you mean mails sent in Android are being downloaded into the Inbox folder of Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook does not recognise the mail as being sent from you, because of the way Gmail works.

Create a filter to erase these emails, or not download them.

This happens on BlackBerry as well, and the fix is to filter emails from the BlackBerry site for your service provider to not download these messages.

Comment: I see now! I will create a filter then to archive the mails that are sent from my own address. This way they wont download on outlook. Thanks a lot!